# Compress mask using AVX intrinsics

Tags: c, x86, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'd like to combine two 256 bit vectors (`__m256d`) which contain the masks as a result of a comparison-operation (such as `_mm256_cmp_pd`) to one 256 bit vector, by omitting the upper half of every 64 bit double.

So, if in the following, `a_i, b_i, ...` are 32 bit words, and I have two 256 bit (4 x double) vectors that have the following structure:

`a_0, a_0, b_0, b_0, c_0, c_0, d_0, d_0`, and `a_1, a_1, b_1, b_1, c_1, c_1, d_1, d_1`.

I'd like to have a single 256 bit vector with the following structure:

`a_0, b_0, c_0, d_0, a_1, b_1, c_1, d_1`.

How do I do this efficiently using Intel intrinsics? The instruction set available is everything up to AVX.

Comment: I assume you intended _mm_cmp_pd in place of __mm_cmp_pd. But _mm_cmp_pd returns __m128d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you can exploit the fact that a bit pattern of all 1s is a `NaN` in both single and double precision, and similarly a bit pattern of all 0s is a 0.0 in both cases. So to pack your two double mask vectors to a single float vector you can do this:

```
 __m256 v = _mm256_set_m128(_mm256_cvtpd_ps(v0), _mm256_cvtpd_ps(v1));
```

Note that if you do not have `_mm256_set_m128` then you can define it as:

```
#define _mm256_set_m128(va, vb) \
        _mm256_insertf128_ps(_mm256_castps128_ps256(vb), va, 1)
```

Here's a demo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

#define _mm256_set_m128(va, vb) \
        _mm256_insertf128_ps(_mm256_castps128_ps256(vb), va, 1)

static void printvd(const char * label, __m256d v)
{
    int64_t a[4];
    _mm256_storeu_pd((double *)a, v);
    printf("%s = %lld %lld %lld %lld\n", label, a[0],  a[1],  a[2],  a[3]);
}

static void printvf(const char * label, __m256 v)
{
    int32_t a[8];
    _mm256_storeu_ps((float *)a, v);
    printf("%s = %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d\n", label, a[0],  a[1],  a[2],  a[3],  a[4],  a[5],  a[6],  a[7]);
}

int main()
{
    __m256d v0 = _mm256_set_pd(0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
    __m256d v1 = _mm256_set_pd(3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    __m256d vcmp0 = _mm256_cmp_pd(v0, v1, 1);
    __m256d vcmp1 = _mm256_cmp_pd(v1, v0, 1);
    __m256 vcmp = _mm256_set_m128(_mm256_cvtpd_ps(vcmp0), _mm256_cvtpd_ps(vcmp1));
    printvd("vcmp0", vcmp0);
    printvd("vcmp1", vcmp1);
    printvf("vcmp ", vcmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
$ gcc -Wall -mavx so_avx_test.c && ./a.out
vcmp0 = 0 0 -1 -1
vcmp1 = -1 -1 0 0
vcmp  = -1 -1 0 0 0 0 -1 -1
```

Comment: It will be tough to do much better without AVX2.

Comment: The only compiler I have that defines _mm256_set_m128() is Visual Studio 2013 and it doesn't accept this code due to argument type. Are the cast intrinsics correct?

Comment: @ScottD: no problem - I've added a macro for `_mm256_set_m128` to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks for the _mm256_set_m128 macro, that is the same one VS2013 is using. But the problem remains: the code doesn't build due to incorrect argument type.

Comment: Sorry - there was one small typo (`__m256d` should have been `__m256`), which I've now fixed. I've also added demo code, which seems to work (with my compiler, at least).

Comment: @PaulR - how does one choose the value of predicate in  https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524076 ? In your case it is 1 but some code I am looking at they set it to be 30. How does one choose that value ?

Comment: @gansub: the predicates are defined in immintrin.h, and they are also listed in the Intel Intrinsics Guide: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=mm256_cmp_pd&expand=712

Answer (score 2):

In the code below, `function1()` performs the operation. The main program supplies sample data and prints results. The FFFFFFFF portions of the sample data are the upper halves to be omitted. The remaining dwords of sample data contain unique patterns. The program output is:

```
v0=A0000000 FFFFFFFF B0000000 FFFFFFFF C0000000 FFFFFFFF D0000000 FFFFFFFF
v1=A0000001 FFFFFFFF B0000001 FFFFFFFF C0000001 FFFFFFFF D0000001 FFFFFFFF
vr=A0000000 B0000000 C0000000 D0000000 A0000001 B0000001 C0000001 D0000001
```

The code was tested with VS2013 using command line `cl /Ox /arch:AVX sample.c` and with gcc 4.9.0 using command line `gcc -O3 -mavx -c sample.c`.

The limited cross-lane capability of AVX makes the solution relatively complicated.

```
#include <intrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

static void dump (void *data)
    {
    uint32_t *d32 = data;
    int index;

    for (index = 0; index < 8; index++)
        printf ("%08X ", d32 [index]);
    printf ("\n");
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 static __m256d function1 (__m256d v0, __m256d v1)
    {
    __m256d tmp0 = _mm256_permute2f128_pd (v0, v1, 0x20);
    __m256d tmp1 = _mm256_permute2f128_pd (v0, v1, 0x31);
    return _mm256_castps_pd (_mm256_shuffle_ps (_mm256_castpd_ps (tmp0), _mm256_castpd_ps (tmp1), 0x88));
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void)
    {
    __m256d v0, v1, vr;

    v0 = _mm256_castsi256_pd (_mm256_set_epi32 (0xffffffff, 0xd0000000, 0xffffffff, 0xc0000000, 0xffffffff, 0xb0000000, 0xffffffff, 0xa0000000));
    v1 = _mm256_castsi256_pd (_mm256_set_epi32 (0xffffffff, 0xd0000001, 0xffffffff, 0xc0000001, 0xffffffff, 0xb0000001, 0xffffffff, 0xa0000001));
    vr = function1 (v0, v1);
    printf ("v0="); dump (&v0);
    printf ("v1="); dump (&v1);
    printf ("vr="); dump (&vr);
    return 0;
    }
```